# increase distance between stack of geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some diffraction data from XRD. I'd like to plot it all in one chart but stacked. Because the range of y is quite large, stacking is not so straight forward. there's a link to data if you wish to play and the simple script is below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9kyubzncwxge9j/xrd.csv?dl=0

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#load it up
xrd <- read.csv("xrd.csv")
#melt it

xrd.m = melt(xrd, id.var="Degrees_2_Theta")
# Reorder so factor levels are grouped together

xrd.m$variable = factor(xrd.m$variable, 
                        levels=sort(unique(as.character(xrd.m$variable))))
names(xrd.m)[names(xrd.m) == "variable"] <- "Sample"
names(xrd.m)[names(xrd.m) == "Degrees_2_Theta"] <- "angle"

#colours use for nearly everything

cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

#plot
ggplot(xrd.m, aes(angle, value, colour=Sample, group=Sample)) +
  geom_line(position = "stack") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",  
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
  labs(x="Degrees 2-theta", y="Intensity - stacked for clarity")
```

[Here is the plot- as you can see it's not quite stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkC0.jpg)

[Here is something I had in excel a way back. ugly - but slightly better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUaZL.png)

I'm not sure that I will actually use the stacked plot function from R because I find it always looks off from past experience and instead might use the same data manipulation I used from excel.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a different understanding of the result of applying `position="stack"` on your `geom_line()` than what actually is happening.  What you're looking to do is probably best served by either using **faceting** or creating a **ridgeline plot**.  I will give you solutions for both of those approaches here with some example data (sorry, I don't click dropbox links and they will eventually break anyway).

#### What does `position="stack"` actually do?

The result of `position="stack"` will be that your y values of each line will be added, or "stacked", together in the resulting plot.  That means that the lines as drawn will only actually accurately reflect the *actual* value in the data for one of the lines, and the other will be "added on top" of that (stacked).  The behavior is best illustrated via an example:

```
ex <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), y=c(1,5,1,2,1,1), grp=rep(c('A','B'),3))
ggplot(ex, aes(x,y, color=grp)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

The y values for "A" are equal to 1 at all values of x.  This is the same as indicating `position="identity"`.  Now, let's see what happens if we use `position="stack"`:

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x,y, color=grp)) + geom_line(position="stack")
```

[image]

You should see, the value of y plotted for "B" is equal to B, whereas the y value for "A" is actually the value for "A" *added to* the value for "B".  Hope that makes sense.

#### Faceting

What you're trying to do is take the overlapping lines you have and "separate" them vertically, right?  That's not quite stacking, as you likely want to maintain their y values as `position="identity"` (the default).  One way to do that quite easily is to use **faceting**, which creates what you could call "stacked plots" according to one or two variables in your dataset.  In this case, I'm using example data (for reasons outlined above), but you can use this to understand how you want to arrange your own data.

```
set.seed(1919191)
df <- data.frame(
  x=rep(1:100, 5),
  y=c(rnorm(100,0,0.1), rnorm(100,0,0.2), rnorm(100,0,0.3), rnorm(100,0,0.4), rnorm(100,0,0.5)),
  sample_name=c(rep('A',100), rep('B',100), rep('C',100), rep('D',100), rep('E',100)))

# plot code
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=sample_name))
p + geom_line() + facet_grid(sample_name ~ .)
```

[image]

#### Create a Ridgeline Plot

The other way that kind of does the same thing is to create what is known as a [ridgeline plot](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/ridgeline.html).  You can do this via the package `ggridges` and here's an example using `geom_ridgeline()`:

```
p + geom_ridgeline(
    aes(y=sample_name, height=y),
    fill=NA, scale=1, min_height=-Inf)
```

[image]

The idea here is to understand that `geom_ridgeline()` changes your y axis to be the grouping variable (so we actually have to redefine that in `aes()`), and the actual y value for each of those groups should be assigned to the `height=` aesthetic.  If you have data that has negative y values (now `height=` values), you'll also want to set the `min_height=`, or it will cut them off at 0 by default.  You can also change how much each of the groups are separated by playing with `scale=` (does not always change in the way you think it would, btw).

Comment: thanks for taking the time with this. I feel silly for even suggesting stacking - seems pretty useless. geom_ridgeline worked perfectly - here's a link to the ridgeline package manual for anyone who is interested: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/ggridges.pdf